# One custom Open Graph object type with multiple urls?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been following Facebooks Open Graph tutorials (the Scrumptious tutorial to be precise) for an Android app that lets the user post a custom story. I've got everything set up and working, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding the object types correctly. In the Scrumptious tutorial they have an `eat` action and a `meal` object, that much I can understand. What I don't fully understand is that there are different `meals`. For example there could be a hamburger `meal`, a pizza `meal`, chili `meal`, etc. Now those are all meals, but each one is different, do I have to set each one up as its own object type? Or do I just keep the single `meal` object and just pass in the different urls (each has its own image and description) associated with the different foods to create the story like I have it setup currently? I probably missed something along the way explaining that, so any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create an object `Meal`, and then using different `URLs`.

The URLs are defined in strings.XML, and they are fetched in SelectionFragment.java, in this line:

```
    foodUrls = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_og_urls);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's how I've got it set currently, just wasn't sure.